# Регулярные выражения js не работает

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
    str.match(/^(.+?)[(\\\()(\$\$)]?/)[1]
```

Подскажите, что не так? Проблема вот в чем. Дана строка. Я должен вывести с начала строки столько символов, пока после них не будет либо сочетание \(, либо $$, либо конец строки. Нужно это строку выдать из первого кармана. Я плохо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, поэтому не могу понять, почему мне, например, в строке "Hello\(" или подобных выдается не "Hello", а только первый символ, т.е. "H". Помогите исправить регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в использовании `[]` в этом случае символы внутри скобок рассматриваются как альтернативы.

Вместо этого можно применить [positive lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Other_assertions), в котором перечислить альтернативы через `|`,

```
/^(.+?)(?=\\\(|\$\$|$)/
```

```js
console.log('Hello\\('.match(/^(.+?)(?=\\\(|\$\$|$)/)[1])
```